# Soundcloud Javascript SDK 2.0 - Stream onfinish event does not execute

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm trying to use the onfinish event for the Soundcloud Javascript SDK Stream method. I have the following code that is working except for the onfinish event never fires. Any ideas would be very helpful.

```
var soundPlayer;
var smOptions = {
    useHTML5Audio: true,
    preferFlash: false,
    onfinish: function() {
        console.log('Finished playing');
    }
};

SC.initialize({
    client_id: "..."
});

SC.stream("/tracks/12345", smOptions, function(sound) {
    soundPlayer = sound;
});
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Since onfinish does not work I am using the getState() method on the soundPlayer object that is returned in SC.stream(). Thankfully there is a unique state called "ended" when the stream has completed. This is what I have implemented:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (soundPlayer != null && soundPlayer.getState() == "ended") {
        soundPlayer.play();
    }
}, 250);
```

I'm not happy about it, but it gives me the experienced desired and meets the requirements. I really hope someone can help shed some light on this on why the documented onfinish method is not firing.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workaround with callbacks instead of polling. It works by targeting the dynamic html5 audio player element itself & registering a native event.  I don't expect it to work in fallback modes, but forcing html5 may finish up the solution until the SDK v2 returns a sound object.

```
var soundPlayer;
var smOptions = {
    useHTML5Audio: true,
    preferFlash: false
};

SC.initialize({
    client_id: "..."
});

SC.stream("/tracks/12345", smOptions, function(sound) {
    soundPlayer = sound;
    html5Audio = sound._player._html5Audio;
    html5Audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){ console.log('event fired: ended'); });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well. Any idea why the stream method does not return a sound object in the callback like the documentation says it does?  https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#streaming

Comment: No problem. I don't have any more info on the SDK, but I'll update this thread if I learn more. Please do the same if you would.

Comment: This works for SDK 2, but since SDK 3 is released (October '15) it's not working anymore. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly with the SDK Version 3

```
SC.stream('/tracks/293', function(player) {
  player.on('finish', function() {
    stopPlayer();
  });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't version 3 SDK return a Promise object? I don't think this solution works. I have tested version 3.1.2 and the callback is never triggered. `.then(fn)` is used instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I can't seem to get any of the callbacks to fire.  Here's a trivial example, working aside from callbacks.  (This should be a comment rather than an answer, but I don't have the SO reputation to do so.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sound Cloud API callback test</h1>
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    SC.initialize({
        client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
    });

    SC.stream(
            '/tracks/293',
            {
                onload: function() { console.log("Does not fire."); },
                onplay: function() { console.log("Does not fire."); },
                onfinish: function() { console.log("Does not fire."); }
            },
            function(sound) { sound.play(); });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, good to know that I'm not going crazy. :) Hopefully we can here from the Soundcloud team or someone that is familiar with this issue. I can't seem to find others having this issue. And all the code I see on SO uses onfinish as I have implemented it. Fingers crossed!

Comment: I can at least verify that if you're going crazy, I am too!  Thanks for posting that workaround. Hopefully we won't need it permanently, but nice to know it's there.