# Sound javascript SDK seeming to not return soundmanager object

Tags: javascript, sdk, soundcloud

I am trying to use this code just to test the soundmanager object that apparently gets passed back from the stream method in the javascript SDK but it doesnt seem to do anything.

```
<script>
SC.initialize({
    client_id: '80df21fc0890334ec86a4c08b787b254'
});

var opts = {
    whileplaying : function() {
        console.log("Hello?");
    }
};

SC.stream("/tracks/115300435", opts, function(sound){

    sound.whileplaying = function()
    {
        console.log("HEY");
    };

    sound.play();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if you use the correct (new) SoundCloud JS SDK.

Actually it looks like there is an issue with the player-events. Maybe this q+a will help you at least a bit further: [SoundCloud SDK / API callback events not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143925/soundcloud-sdk-api-callback-events-not-firing)

If you remove the options, it will work.

```
SC.stream("/tracks/115300435", function(sound){ 
    sound.play();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/9Le6vqrr/

Comment: Thanks, the related link worked perfectly. Or more specifically this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/31170874/4526014 . The answer was to use `<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk-2.0.0.js"></script>`