# Soundcloud stream: onfinish function not working with locked phone

Tags: javascript, php, iphone, web-applications, soundcloud

I have a bit a complicated question, I hope you'll understand.

Here's a short but easy description:

- WebApp with Soundcloud Stream
- onfinish-function: plays random song (onfinish is the state when the stream of - one song is over)
- works when my phone(iPhone with iOS 9) is unlocked and the webapp is opened
- when I lock the phone: song plays to the end but next song won't start automatically
- when I unlock the phone after that the next song starts automatically

Where could be the problem?

Thanks for help

Comment: looks like a possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010292/soundcloud-javascript-sdk-2-0-stream-onfinish-event-does-not-execute

Comment: Thanks for the link. Tried this but I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html5Audio' of undefined`

Comment: maybe update your question with how you tried it and  what line that error is occurring on?

Comment: @TygerKrash This is my code: `function StreamStart(NewID) {
        TrackLink = "/tracks/" + NewID;
        SC.stream(TrackLink, {
            useHTML5Audio: true,
            preferFlash: false,
             whileplaying: function () {
            console.log(this.position);
            }
        
        }, function(sound) {
        soundToPlay = sound;
  playTrackFast();
        html5Audio = sound._player._html5Audio;
        html5Audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){ console.log('event fired: ended'); });
  }
)};`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that soundcloud itself has this problem too. It's probably because of iOS 9 and the new version of safari...
So the problem is not in the code, it's because of apple.

Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: What?..So is it a problem with SC, or Apple?

Comment: I checked the settings but found nothing helpful... The problem is with Safari-it works(mostly) when I use chrome on my iPhone...

Comment: Explain the difference between what happens on Chrome vs Safari please.

Comment: On Chrome the next song starts playing automatically when a song is over also when the iPhone is locked or when I'm in a different app. But on Safari it doesn't play automatically, I have to go to the browser. As soon as the phone is unlocked and the site is opened again the next song starts.

Comment: well then it's theoretically a issue with Safari, but you got nothing to lose in writing about that to SoundCloud: Support @ soundcloud . com (if it's still available).

Comment: Good luck, and let us know.

Comment: Ok I did this but there's a automatic reply. It says I should visit the Support Center(which is Stackoverflow)... Do you have more ideas? @DaniSpringer

Comment: SoundCloud has no connection with StackOverFlow. By help center they meant the one on help . SoundCloud . com , or whatever the link is. But you can find it easily by visiting their site. Soundcloud . Com

Comment: On developer.soundcloud.com/support it says _"Our team is answering technical questions on Stack Overflow"_ So there is a connection. The normal support won't answer my question I think.. @DaniSpringer

Comment: Ok that's new. Have you found help . Soundcloud ?

Comment: @DaniSpringer Yes, this site is active.

Comment: Try contacting regular support, not developer.

Comment: @DaniSpringer Ok, I try this. I'll let you know as soon as I got an answer. Ok, I'll add the code to the main question.

Comment: @DaniSpringer So.. I tried multiple times and wrote like 3-4 emails but I didn't get an answer... I think that I'll only use chrome on my iPhone by now. Thanks for your help anyway!