# How do I attach the Soundcloud API SDK 3.0 on(finish, handler) method to my Play function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, soundcloud

I don't see any answers on how to use the on(event, handler) method for the current version of the SoundCloud JS sdk.

Any ideas on how I would attach it to my play function? I want it to play the next song when the current song finishes. Here's my play function:

```
  $scope.play = function(id) {
    soundcloud.stream(id).then(function(player) {
      $scope.player = player;
      $scope.player.play();
    });
    $scope.isPlaying = id;
  };
```

I already have a stepForward function that I could call, e.g., `on(finish, $scope.StepForward());` but there's no indication of where I would put this in the docs: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have good experience with this particular API, so this is more of a comment, but I don't have the karma to leave one. It says in those docs that on(event, handler) is a function of the player, so I think you should be able to set on that event listener when you set up the player. Try adding this right after the `$scope.player.play()` line.

```
$scope.player.on('finished', $scope.StepForward);
```

Also, you shouldn't actually call the handler function in the `.on()`, you just pass the function and it gets called when the event happens.

Comment: You're on the right track with your answer with some minor edits. I did `$scope.player.on('finish', $scope.StepForward());`. It caused the player to freak out, so I also just did a good ol' console.log... `$scope.player.on('finish', console.log('finished'));` For some reason, it triggers immediately upon playing rather than at the end of the track...

Comment: It triggered immediately because you called the function (you included parenthesis at the end of it). You don't need the anonymous function either, you can just pass the function without calling it in as the event handler callback.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Brannon. I did end up using a a callback function so that I could use `$scope.$apply` (see my answer to my own question). It wouldn't surprise me if you have a cleaner alternative though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on a comment someone had posted here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010292/soundcloud-javascript-sdk-2-0-stream-onfinish-event-does-not-execute/33742829#33742829)

The question was actually regarding SDK 2.0, but the comment was the answer to my question for SDK 3.0.

```
$scope.player.on('finish' function() {
  $scope.stepForward();
  $scope.$apply; // in my case, this updates a variable, $scope.isPlaying, to the DOM
});
```

I guess I'm used to this being referred to as a callback not a handler. Now I know that a handler is a type of callback.

Answer (score -1):

I use the following code which lives within a function loadAndUpdate:

```
player.addEventListener('ended', function () {

    var nextCount = 1;
    nextTrack(nextCount);

    function nextTrack(nextCount) {
        QueueControl('forward', function () {
            if (typeof playList[playTrack] == 'undefined') {
                writeHistory('player ended ' + nextCount + ': playList[playTrack] == "undefined"');
                nextTrack(nextCount + 1);
            } else {
                loadAndUpdate(playList[playTrack], loader, audioSource, player, cpUpdate);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

the 'undefined' check is a fix for CORS issues I get with 25% of the files chosen, so the code just pings to the next track in the list. it is on my fix list...